# Zendesk - Listen agent response event ZAF Client [Support Location]

Tags: javascript, zendesk, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

for a while now I am stuck, trying to listen to the event where the agent sends a reply to the ticket. I have tried listening to `ticket.comments.changed` and `ticket.conversation.changed` but have not been successful.

I can't use the `ticket.submit.[done|fail|always]` or `ticket.save` because I don't have a way of knowing if it is the event I want or is being called with another event.

Maybe someone who knows of a configuration or some way that would allow me to do this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Both events are not suitable as they will only fire after the save hook has allowed the ticket to be submitted. Please share more about your use case to suggest a suitable approach.

Comment: Hi @ahmedsabriz, thank you for replying... what I want to do is to send the ticket payload to a webhook every time the ticket changes status or the agent adds a response.

Comment: It sounds like you could use a trigger for that instead of an app.

Comment: Yes, but I need to store the app in the zendesk marketplace, so I can't use triggers to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure triggers and webhooks to be added to your app as [requirements](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/app-developer-guide/apps_requirements/). If you must use a ticket_sidebar app, you can listen to the following events:

```
var client = ZAFClient.init();
    client.on('ticket.comments.changed', (e) => {
        // Here is the latest comment
        let comment = e[0];
        console.log(comment);

        // Check author role
        console.log((comment.author.role !== "end-user") ? "Comment made by agent" : "Comment made by end user");
        
        // Get ticket object if needed
        client.get('ticket').then(
            (res) => {
                // Send ticket payload to my backend
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            }
        )
    });
    client.on('ticket.status.changed', (e) => {
        // Here is the new status
        console.log("Status changed to", e);
        
        // Get ticket object if needed
        client.get('ticket').then(
            (res) => {
                // Send ticket payload to my backend
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            }
        )
    });
```

Comment: I tried that. The `ticket.comments.changed` trigger is never called. But, I fixed it, I am listening to the trigger `ticket.submit.start` and validating when the comment text is empty. Thank you for taking the time to help me!!